# How to move through words in camel-cased identifiers in Vim?

Tags: vim

How to move the cursor before or after the first uppercase letter of a word in Vim?

My motivation is removing or selecting the first word of a camel-case identifier in code. For example, if the cursor is on the `m` character in the word `camelCase`, I can use the `FcdtC` sequence of Normal-mode commands to delete the `camel` prefix.

Is there a general way to jump to the next occurrence of an uppercase letter in an identifier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>I don't think there is anything built-in.</strike>

As [@ib. indicates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8951272/254635), you can use a regular expression motion, but it’s not particularly easy to type. However, there is [camelcasemotion plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1905) that adds the necessary motions, for this, as well as underscore seperated identifiers.

Comment: Plug-in is ideal because of all the other things that come with it, but with respect to the regex motion typing, once hidden in a mapping, there is nothing lost and a little knowledge learned.  Actually, for kicks, I suggest cracking the plug-in open and seeing how they map their own command for this :)

Answer (score 24):

In situations where approaches using only built-in Vim instruments are
preferred, the following search commands can be used.

For jumping to the next uppercase character:

```
/\u
```

For moving the cursor one character to the right of the next uppercase
character:

```
/\u/s+
```

or

```
/\u\zs
```

If one expects to use a movement like that often, one can always
define a key mapping for it as a shorthand, e.g.:

```
:nnoremap <leader>u /\u/s+<cr>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think I thought maybe "the vim way" to do it :

Vim allow us to define our own operator !

```
" movement mapping {
" Delete yank or change until next UpperCase
" o waits for you to enter a movement command : http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/15.html
" M is for Maj (as in french)
" :<c-u>execute -> special way to run multiple normal commande in a map : learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/16.html

onoremap M :<c-u>execute "normal! /[A-Z]\r:nohlsearch\r"<cr>
```

That way giving

```
DailyAverage.new(FooBarBaz)
```

If my cursor is on `a` (from DailyMesure) and I press `dM` It delete to A and give

```
Average.new(FooBarBaz)
```

It works with all command waiting for a movement (`c` `y` ........)

This snippet need to be improved because of bad highlight.

Answer (score 3):

#### Updated Answer (using @ib.'s contribution)

```
"select from first char up to First uppercase letter ( after first char )
map ,b bv/[A-Z]<cr>h
```

#### Original Answer

Regarding jumping before and after the first uppercase letter—
You can map it if you want to.

```
"Before next uppercase letter
map ,A /[A-Z]<cr>l

"After next uppercase letter
map ,B /[A-Z]<cr>h
```

:D.  Hope this helps.  I'm reading your second question now.

Ok, read it.  Now you can do this

```
bv,A
```

:D

Comment: too complicated and subject to malfunctioning depending of the `'ignorecase'` parameter (though it works with both `'ignorecase'` and `'smartcase'`).

Comment: Good point on 'ignorecase'.  I don't see the complexity though.  Perhaps a one-keystroke mapping?  I do like @ib.'s suggestion better though.

What do you think about this, assuming one is not using 'ignorecase'?

   map <F2> /\u<cr>h

Comment: I meant `[A-Z]` is too complicated. `\u` is 50% less characters. But that's just being pecky :)