# IdeaVim move between words in camel case word

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

I am new to vim and IdeaVim. Is there a way to move to the next word in camel case word?
[c]amelCaseWord -> w -> camel[C]aseWord -> w -> camelCase[W]ord

Comment: Tried https://stackoverflow.com/q/8949317/7976758 ? Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+words+camel+case

Comment: a) Vim doesn't know about camelCase, b) Ideavim is not Vim, c) isn't it a native feature of all JetBrains IDEs anyway?

Comment: @romainl a) that's why I have asked the question? b) yes, but you can add all vim settings to Ideavim. c) yes, it is but with ctrl and arrows. And as you can see, I asked if there is a way to do it with 'w' in Ideavim

Comment: a) What you have is a limited Vim emulator and a powerful IDE, here. Vim is not involved in this at any point so whether it can do X or Y is immaterial. b) No, you can't. c) Ideavim has official support channels.

Comment: @romainl b) https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim#Files `You can read your ~/.vimrc file from ~/.ideavimrc with this command:`. Isn't it import settings from vim?

Comment: It is "import settings from vim" but not "you can add all vim settings to Ideavim", simply because Ideavim doesn't support *all* Vim functionalities.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IdeaVim supports camel case motions out of the box: `]w`, `[w`, `]b`, `[b`
It is also possible to remap default motions to the camel case ones in your ideavimrc/vimrc:

```
 map w [w
 map e ]w
 map b [b
```

Comment: for some reason it works, but I need to press '[' every time before pressing w. I can't just keep pressing '[' and pressing w. The second time I press 'w' with already pressed '[' it will just skip all camel case word. Is there any workaround? And if it's possible to remap default motions - please specify how.

Comment: Adding this lines to your ~/.ideavimrc should help 
(IdeaVim icon in the IDE statusbar -> "Create ~/.ideavimrc")
`
map w [w
map e ]w
map b [b
`
Then you should source your ideavimrc - `:source ~/.ideavimrc` or simply restart the IDE for the changes in ideavimrc to take effect

p.s. IdeaVim is highly customizable and has it's own cool features (e.g. executing IDE actions), so https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim ReadMe file is definitely worth checking out, have a nice day!

Comment: How do you intuitively remember what the `[` and the `]` mean? While sure, it might become a muscle memory with enough use, even ChatGPT couldn't come up with a way to remember the "why" of the brackets.

Answer (score 4):

If prefer not to override default "b" and "w". I use with <leader> key for camel/snake motion. Hence, I map this;

```
map <leader>w [w
map <leader>b [b
```

After navigating using "<leader>w", to change the camel/snake word,
"c<leader>w" works without extra mapping.

But for the case, "J" down from live above and land in the middle of the camel/snake word and want to change, like in camel motion plugin, I map this to get "ci" (change inside);

```
map ci<leader>w [bv]ws
```

My "<leader>" key is space.

```
let mapleader = " "
```